# How to bind a child link to it's parent container

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have some html that on mobile the link is too small to click on the text link so I would like to make the entire parent container clickable on mobile only. How can I bind the child anchor with the "show-for-small-only class link to the parent div?

```
    @media #{$small-only} {
        .show-for-small-only {
             display: block;
        }

       .hide-for-small-only {
             display: none;
        }
   .parent {
       cursor: pointer;
         }
    }


    <div class=“parent”>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <a href=“myLink1” class="show-for-small-only">My link</a>
        <a href=“myLink1" class="hide-for-small-only”>My Normal link</a>
    </div>

    <div class=“parent”>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <a href=“myLink2” class="show-for-small-only">My link2</a>
        <a href=“myLink2" class="hide-for-small-only”>My Normal link 2</a>
    </div>

    <div class=“parent”>
        <p>Some Text</p>
        <a href=“myLink3” class="show-for-small-only">My link3</a>
        <a href=“myLink3" class="hide-for-small-only”>My Normal link 3</a>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do something like this - which could be simplified or written in a number of different ways:

```
$(".parent").bind("click", function(){
    window.location.href = $(".parent a").attr("href");
});
```

Comment: This is what I ended up with. Your answer partially worked however it was always clicking the first url even if I clicked the 2nd or 3rd. I added the var ThisLink to find the current child a. Thanks

`$(".parent").bind("click", function(){
    var thisLink = $(this).find(".show-for-small-only");
    window.location.href = thisLink.attr("href");
});`

Answer (score 0):

```
$(".parent show-for-small-only").click(function(){
    var link=$(this).find("a").attr("href");
    window.location.href = link;
});
```

Comment: I ended up doing some like this:

   ` $(".parent show-for-small-only").click(function(e){
        e.stopPropagation();
        e.preventDefault
    $(this).find(".show-for-small-only").click();
   });`

The problem is, it's clicking every link with the .show-for-small-only class. I used.

Comment: You can use this selelctor     $(".parent show-for-small-only:has(a)")